# MVC 3 validation: Can I have multiple Error Msgs in multiple places for each control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

[image: Data Entry Page and Validation Errors]

This is my MVC registration page. You can see the validation error messages consolidated up top. The UI designers want red (*) to appear next to each control that needs attention.

I know how to use MVC 3 validation to produce either *'s or the error messages above by placing @Html.ValidationMessageFor and customizing error messages to be either *'s of the more detailed messages.

What I can't figure out is how to do both. I understand that I can solve this problem with JQuery. But I suspect that MVC validation has a way to do this. @Html.ValidationMessageFor seems to apply once for each model member / control so that is probably not the way...

So to summarize, is there a way for me to add a second error message (like *) for each control located in a different location than the original message with only MVC validation and no JQuery / JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the validation feedback only supports one feedback string per input. You could set custom feedback messages for each one and put the * in front of the string but this breaks a lot of the convention over configuration benefit of MVC.

Now, that being said why not try CSS? As I understand it those feedback messages (when next to each input form) use a fixed css class. So maybe something along this line...

```
field-validation-error:before
{ 
    content:"* ";
}
```

Comment: thats a pretty kool idea. I have to look closer at that!

Comment: While it's a good idea, I realize it has same drawbacks as James's suggestion of using validation summary and ValidationMessageFor. As the css would not be next to the control's label as I want, but next to the error. But its a creative approach and confirms what everyone is telling me... Summary and individual messages for the *'s.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Your original question asked to place the * next to the control that needed attention, not the label for that control. I wonder if you could place it next to the label using CSS as well? Something for the label that requires there to be a sibling span with that class maybe? I've not tried this but like you said, jQuery could probably do it as well.

Comment: Yarx, I found I need this afterall. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Html.ValidationSummary at the top. Html.ValidationMessageFor next to each field.

Comment: James, thanks, that would partially solve my problem. Only issue is the Validation Summary only gets populated if they hit submit. And that's not terrible. But I like that the unobtrusive javascript acts without having to hit submit. Is there a way to achieve this while keeping it Ajax-ish?